# Am I able to solve $xe^x<1$?

Tags: inequality, polynomials, exponential-function

Can I solve manually the inequality $xe^x<1$? Or any other exponential times polynomial inequality.

Comment: With solve manually you mean an analytic solution like $x<x_0$ where there's some explicit formula for $x_0$?

Comment: @qbert yes. Actually, first I want to know if there is a way of doing it directly. And then we think about graphically. Graphically, I tried to discover the "x's" where e^x =1, and x=1, and I did a table with the sign "+" or "-", considering y=1 like y=0. But I guess it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you heard of the Lambert W function?

Comment: @projectilemotion no.. But is there a way to calculate analitically this inequalitiy: 2^x*(x^2+x+1)<6

Comment: Probably not. However, $xe^x<1$ can be analytically found to be $x<W(1)$ since the inverse function of $f(x)=xe^x$ is the Lambert W function. The Omega constant is in fact equivalent to $W(1)$. However, note that $W(x)$ is not injective.

Comment: @projectilemotion I would say using $W$, at least in a problem this simple, is at most a rewriting, and not a solution. But then again, the exact same thing can be said about saying that the solutions to $x^2=2$ are $\pm\sqrt2$, so I'm not really consistent in that respect.

Comment: @Arthur Its not so bad if you start with a specific case, and then extend through to a more general case using some algebra.  Then it isn't so bad.

Answer (score 5):

The solution to the equation $xe^x=1$ is famously known as the [Omega constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega_constant), and for $x<\Omega$, we have

$$xe^x<1$$

For linear functions and exponential functions, we have the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert%27s_W_function),

$$p^x=ax+b\implies x=\frac{W\left(-\frac{\ln p}ap^{-b/a}\right)}{-\ln p}-\frac ba$$

However, with the exception of special cases like $(x+1)^2e^x=4$ which may be reduced to a linear function times an exponential function via square rooting and such, I know not of a general solution in terms of special functions when it does not reduce to a linear function times the exponential function.

Comment: ok, thanks for your answer. Consider now: 2^x*(x^2+x+1)<6

Comment: @VitorAguiar In general, one cannot solve analytically in terms of well known functions for quadratics and higher degree polynomials.  Note however that $2^x(x^2+2x+1)=2^x(x+1)^2=6\implies(\sqrt2)^x(x+1)=\sqrt6\implies\frac1{\sqrt6}x+\frac1{\sqrt6}=(2^{-1/2})^x$ which reduces to the above case.